Short story set in a village in the middle of a nuclear war
This one is for my husband who has been trying to identify a short story with the following premise:
He is unsure about the setting - he thinks it is set in an English village with a pub.
The characters find themselves sealed in on three sides of the village by mysterious forcefields that burn anything pushed through them. The discover that these walls are gradually closing in.
The explanation is nuclear war, with three bombs exploding simultaneously nearby and almost, but not quite, freezing time in the space between them.

Does he have any idea when he would have read this?  It sounds like a 1960s story to me, but it's possible it could have been later.  Unlikely to be after the 1980s though.

He isnt sure, he thinks he read it in the 1980s but could, of course, have been an older story

US sci-fi : often set in empty wasteland.  UK scfi - local pub !  Bit of the old national character showing there. :-)

This is ringing a faint bell. Does it start when someone goes out of the pub then comes back in ashen faced having seen the walls and the others in the pub accuse hm of being drunk and having hallucinations?

He thinks so but can't remember enough of the story I'm afraid
